# UNIX valid_password

Tags: unix, if-statement, cygwin, ubuntu-10.10

why in Cygwin Terminal - the if statement work
and ubuntu - unix - not working   for
this code :

```
#!/bin/sh
valid_password="pass"

echo "Please enter the password:"
read password

if [ "$password" == "$valid_password" ]
then
   echo "You have access!"
else
   echo "Access denied!"
fi
```

Comment: It's not working is not helpful! How is it not working? What error messages are seen. I suspect the file has DOS line ending try `dos2unix file`

Comment: will it work with `#!/bin/bash` instead of `sh`?  also, i'd recommend you change the double quotes in your echo commands to single quotes so that the shell doesn't try to interpret the `!` as a history reference.

Answer (score 1):

because the correct syntax to `[` is:

```
[ a = b ]
```

From your error message it sounds like you wrote:

```
if ["$password" = "$valid_password" ]
```

change this to:

```
if [ "$password" = "$valid_password" ]
```

notice the space after `[`. `if` just takes a shell command, try to run it and depending if the exit code from the program is `0` it will run the commands inside the `if` statement.

In your terminal, write i.e.:

```
user@localhost$ true; echo $?
0
```

to test your if statement:

```
user@localhost$ pass=pass; valid=pass
user@localhost$ if [ "$pass" = "$valid" ]; then echo 'You have access!'; fi
```

As @nullrevolution said, the `!` is evaluated if you use double quotes, it will try to run last command in your shell history, in this case that is matching `u`.

```
user@localhost$ uname
Linux
user@localhost$ !u
uname
Linux
user@localhost$ echo "!"
sh: !: event not found
```

This is because the `!` is evaluated before the double quotes are matched, and echo is run. If you still want to use double quotes, you will have to escape the `!` outside the quotes:

```
echo "Access denied"\!
```

@nullrevolution also said you could try with `bash`, which has a builtin syntax for the expression inside if statements.

```
#!/bin/bash

valid_password=pass

echo "Please enter the password:"
read password

if [[ "$password" == "$valid_password" ]]; then
    echo 'You have access!'
else
    echo 'Access denied!'
fi
```

Also in your program I guess you do not want to echo the password in the terminal, to turn off echo temporary change:

```
read password
```

to

```
stty -echo
read password
stty echo
```

if you forgot to write `stty echo` to turn on echo again, just write `reset` in your terminal, and it will reset the terminal to default settings.

A useful tutorial for bourn shell script can be found here:

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html

Comment: sorry  but is not working , maybe i need do Something in ubuntu ?

Comment: shay@ubuntu:~/scripts$ ./password          
Please enter the password:            
pass           
./password: 12: [pass: not found          
Access denied!

Comment: Good! Then mark it as accepted answer (you do it next to my answer), so the question will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

@emil pointed the answer:

```
if [ "$password" = "$valid_password" ]
```

instead of

```
if [ "$password" == "$valid_password" ]
```

Also: did you give the script executing permissions? Try

```
chmod +x script_name
```

Comment: shay@ubuntu:~/scripts$ ./password          
Please enter the password:            
pass           
./password: 12: [pass: not found          
Access denied!

Comment: yes i give chmod 777  ,  dos2unix is in Cygwin - is work , but no in ubuntu